# hard time to make the W3C AppML tutorial example working

Tags: javascript, php, soa

I try the tutorial appml on w3c

Nothing is working... ><

I downloaded appml for php, here : http://www.w3schools.com/appml/appml_download.asp

I put files in a folder called "appml"

```
drwxr-xr-x  16 g_pierr  wheel    544 31 oct 18:25 Images
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 g_pierr  wheel   7402 26 sep  2013 appml.css
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 g_pierr  wheel  75662  7 jan  2014 appml.js
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 g_pierr  wheel  32956  7 jan  2014 appml.php
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 g_pierr  wheel    389 31 oct 18:43 appml_config.php
-rw-r--r--   1 g_pierr  wheel    142 31 oct 18:42 customers.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 g_pierr  wheel    401 31 oct 18:41 index.htm
```

the appml_config.php is :

```
<?php echo("Access Forbidden");exit(); ?>

<appml>

<database name="appmldemo">
<host>localhost:3306</host>
<name>test_db</name>
<user>root</user>
<password>root</password>
</database>

<database name="appmlsecurity">
<host>localhost:3306</host>
<name> test_db</name>
<user>root</user>
<password>root</password>
</database>

<dateformat>yyyy-mm-dd</dateformat>
```

test_db exists and credentials working. 
test_db contains the northwind content, which is a well-known sample SQL used for tests.

The appml.js has not been modified.
The appml_config.php has not been modified.

I have customers.xml for handle data

```
<appml>

<datasource>
<database>
  <connection>appmldemo</connection>
  <sql>SELECT * FROM customers</sql>
</database>
</datasource>

</appml>
```

and I have index.html on the 'view' part

```
<h1>My First Web Application</h1>

<div id="Place01">
<table id="Template01" class="appmltable">
<tr>
  <th>Customer</th>
  <th>City</th>
 <th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr id="appml_row">
  <td>#CustomerName#</td>
  <td>#City#</td>
  <td>#Country#</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script src="appml.js"></script>
<script>
app=new AppML("appml_config.php","customers");
app.run("Place01","Template01");
</script>
```

At the end, I got a javascript alert , always the same ><

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
Access Forbidden
```

The deprecated is just a warning I dont care about now.
The second warning is about header already sent by : it doesnt block script execution, then I dont care neither.

The ''Access Forbidden'' string comes from the appml_config.php file

And nothing more...

Does anyone could tell me where I'm wrong in my exact reproduction of what w3c is saying, in what they called 'a tutorial' ? thx you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
app=new AppML("appml_config.php","customers");
```

and change it to this

```
app=new AppML("appml.php","customers");
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot the fact you answered. Unfortunately, I moved on from this topic, because I was very stuck. BUT I'll try your solution asap - need to reinstall everything - and I'll come to share the result here, in order to build a common knowledge on this error. Thx again